# Reading bytes from Silverlight Class Library

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight Class Library and need to read a few bytes of itself into an array. Is it possible at all for a SL DLL to do this without getting the hosting SL site to read it from the XAP?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to open and read the DLL file itself? I don't think you can do that. Try using embedded resources or something instead

Comment: Thanks Stewart.
Yep, that's what I mean - read some bytes from the DLL itself.
I use to embed a resource but was hoping I could avoid it.